# Test non-UI iOS code for both correctness and performance by jailbreaking an Apple TV 2?

Tags: ios, arm

Right now I run tests on all of my cross-platform libraries, except in the case of modern ARM CPUs. I'm starting to port some stuff to iOS, and it seems like $100 is a small amount to pay for a server that I can ssh in to, push some binaries, and gather some metrics.  I don't want to use Qemu, and most Cortex devices are expensive.

It looks like can test Thumb-2 / ARMv7 on an Apple TV 2, although I have no experience with the device.

Does this sound reasonable?  Can I mount a Samba share from a jailbroken Apple TV 2?